# How to disable preview file with single-click in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would much rather double-click to open file, and prevent single-click previews. How do we do that in vs code?

Comment: You can turn off preview by setting `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`, but you could not prevent single-click, which means single-click will open file for editing directly rather than preview.

Comment: You can convert a preview to a true editor with `workbench.action.keepeditor` which is `⌘K, Enter` by default (being buried it's a Sublime Text throwback)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

From vscode **1.20**:

```json
"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick",
```

Comment: I had to fight through a barrage of people answering the wrong question (funnily enough trying to disable preview mode by enabling a more permanent mode actually makes the issue more annoying!) to get to this, thank you @Alex

Comment: I had the exact problem of @jmcgrory, this shoul be marked as solution

Comment: This is wrong. The preview function remains working.

Comment: I upvoted the above comment, but then discovered that after a VS Code reset it worked!

Comment: It's been 3 years and I've just come back from the same issue on a new machine, tried the first (wrong) answer then looked further down and seen that I've not only upvoted but commented.

Those that repeat history @Ares9323 ...

Answer (score 147):

The only way to disable file previewing when clicked on at all is by setting `"workbench.editor.enablePreview"` to `false`.

`"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,`

[image]

Comment: This does NOT change the behaviour, that the file only gets opened in a tab  when double clicked. The only difference is, that it gets opened in "edit mode" rather than in "preview mode".

Comment: That's how you disable file previewing and open the file.  VS Code can't do the double click thing.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Calkins has the correct answer to this issue. This should be marked as correct.

Comment: this is for older version, please look at the top answer

Comment: This also also works for opening files with CTRL+P.

Comment: Thank you I was looking for this one :)

Answer (score 84):

Go to File->Preferences->Settings, search for the following and disable it:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

[image: Italian Trulli]

Comment: Making this change will cause single-clicks to open (rather than preview) files.  If you want to disable all single-click actions, use Alex's suggestion.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. This will open the files on single click. OP and myself wants to disable single click preview and single click file opens. It should be single click selects the file and double click opens it. The issue is that clicking a file in the explorer window opens a preview causing you to lose focus on the document that you want to keep open. Your suggestion to remove previews actually causes automatic file opening, which is a worse disruptive behaviour.

Answer (score 39):

The necessary settings to prevent single-click in the Explorer view opening a file at all are in the previous answers to this question but you need to apply two of them:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

That will change single-click in the explorer to fully open the file instead of opening it in preview (*italics*) mode. Arguably this is worse than before unless you're on a touchscreen device so you also need the following setting:

```
"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick"
```

Now you have to double-click on a file in Explorer to open it and preview is off. Finally, I had to restart all open instances of vscode for the `doubleClick` change to take effect.

vscode is a moving target so I should point out this was tested in version 1.45.1.

Answer (score 11):

Probably you're mixing the terms.
I guess you are talking about "[Peek](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek)" feature:

[image: vscode peek]

And here is how you can disable it:

`"editor.gotoLocation.multipleDefinitions": "goto"`

---

Also, there is a "[Preview editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/June_2016.md#preview-editors)" feature:

[image: vscode preview editor]

That could be disabled by:

`"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

Comment: for me, definitely what I was looking for - thank you

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know there is no way to do this right now (version 1.12).

Many people "requested" this feature, just look [at this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9388).

.. and a relatively new comment about the issue:

> Sorry, didn't have much time to look into this again. As it stands
>   right now we need to clean up some debt first in the area of tree
>   usage throughout our code before we can ask for a PR again.

Comment: That behaviour really annoys me - thanks for the link to the issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the issue was closed. 3 year later this issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Look at the openMode option!

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to set this from UI level if you do not want to edit files directly:
File -> Preferences -> Workbench -> List: Open mode = 'doubleClick'

or

File -> Preferences -> search for 'Open mode' and set it to 'doubleClick'

Answer (score 5):

So I had to do both suggestions by @Alex and @MichaelJ.Calkins. More specifically I had to configure the open mode setting to click and enable preview to true. That way I can preview with a single click and actually keep it open with a double click. Below are the settings that were configured.

```
"workbench.list.openMode": "singleClick",

"workbench.editor.enablePreview": true,
```

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another configuration entry (above the `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": true`) that can prevent VSCode from opening files on new tab is the following:

`"workbench.editor.showTabs": false`

Make sure it is removed from `settings.json` or it is set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for this, The 'preview' feature is garbage according to me.

Answer (score 4):

Go to visual studio code settings on the bottom left and then search for 'preview' settings. Make sure that 'enable preview' is not enabled in 'WorkBench > Editor'

[image: visual studio code settings]