# How to turn off half-open (italic) files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want my editor to work like this:

- Single click on a file in the project tree should **SELECT** the file in the tree.
- Double click should **OPEN** the file **PERMANENTLY**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable preview file with single-click in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336583/how-to-disable-preview-file-with-single-click-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 11):

When you are using vscode v1.20.0 or later add this to your user settings:

```json
"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick"
```

Comment: It also works if you go you to "File -> Preferences -> Settings" and search for `workbench.list.openMode`

Answer (score 7):

Update for VSCode version 1.77.0 and later
To Disable Open file where filename is in italics (Preview Mode)

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

This works when using Go to Definition, and other ways to open files.