# Disable Opening of Large Files in SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is it possible to prevent VSCode from opening large files when in SSH, using the Remote - SSH extension?

If I accidentally click on a large file, the program hangs until it is downloaded or even disconnects.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75178980/836330 for a possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue boring me too and I can not find any plugin does that.

According to [Tips Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336583/how-to-disable-preview-file-with-single-click-in-vs-code),  I just set `workbench.list.openMode` to `doubleClick` to avoid previewing when single click.