# Multiple previews open up when Using Gitlab Workflow extension in VS Code for diff in a merge req

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge, gitlab, diff

**Context:** I am using the [gitlab workflow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow) extension in VS code to review merge requests.

**Problem**: Whenever I click on any file for checking the diff in the merge request, it opens up many preview windows (most probably the number of such preview windows are equal to the number of review comments in the merge request).

[image: I click on a file]
[image: snipping from the tabs opened in vs code]

**Already tried**:[How to disable preview file with single-click in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336583/how-to-disable-preview-file-with-single-click-in-vs-code#)

Comment: the asker seems to have raised an issue ticket: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension/-/issues/1020